# Maven release plugin fails

Tags: maven

I am trying to  make a release and it fails on

> mvn release:perform

The error is

> Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.abondar.experimental.wsboard</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebScrumBoard</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <springboot.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <cxf.version>3.3.2</cxf.version>
        <junit.version>5.3.2</junit.version>
        <jaxb.version>2.3.1</jaxb.version>
        <camel.version>2.24.1</camel.version>
        <build-plugin.jacoco.version>0.8.4</build-plugin.jacoco.version>
        <build-plugin.coveralls.version>4.3.0</build-plugin.coveralls.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <deploy.plugin.version>2.8.1</deploy.plugin.version>
        <nexus.staging.version>1.5.1</nexus.staging.version>
    </properties>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-repositories</id>
            <name>maven snapshots</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-repositories</id>
            <name>maven releases</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:abondar24/WebScrumBoard</connection>
        <url>https://github.com/abondar24/WebScrumBoard</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/abondar24/WebScrumBoard.git</developerConnection>
      <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

    <modules>
        <module>dataModel</module>
        <module>webService</module>
        <module>ui</module>
        <module>dao</module>
        <module>base</module>

    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>
                        11
                    </release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>0</forkCount>

                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>

                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${build-plugin.jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
                <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${build-plugin.coveralls.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${deploy.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${nexus.staging.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>nexus</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>http://localhost:8081/nexus/</nexusUrl>
                    <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I don't understand the problem. Deployment to snapshot repo via deploy-plugin works perfectly

Comment: Not sure, maybe the nexus-staging-maven-plugin causes the problem.

Comment: Are you certain you are looking at the pom.xml which has the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved after a proper rollback and splitting nexus server ids